# Platform-independent, real-time canvas drawing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, real-time

I want to draw on a canvas in real time, possibly set individual pixels, draw geometric shapes like rectangles, and insert images.

This is what I want it to look like:

```py
from greatgui import Window, Canvas
from time import sleep

width = 640
height = 480

w = Window("My title", (width,height))
c = Canvas((width, height))

w.add(c)

i = 0

while True:
    c.putpixel((i, i), color=(255,255,255))
    i += 1
    w.update()
    sleep(0.1)
```

Anything of greater complexity or setup cost is unacceptable. Am I down on my luck?

I have not found a single example of a GUI framework that doesn't require me to:

- create dozens of lines of boilerplate code and platform checks
- install anything extra (especially compile something by hand!), except through pip
- add some callback hook into some framework
- transfer control to any mainloop at all
- renounce all the comfort of Pillow's ImageDraw module

Comment: Why would you want this capability from a programming language? Programs like paint can be used to do all of the things you want. Unless someone has made a package for doing this exact thing, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: @will.evo I don't want to create a static image, otherwise I'd use Pillow's ImageDraw directly. This real-time drawing is (at least for me) a highly common use case any time I want to visualize dynamic systems. So far I had to resort to saving individual images into some directory and then converting that to a gif. That is very slow, inefficient and not immediate however.

Comment: Maybe look at [beeware](https://beeware.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far https://www.pygame.org seems to be a good choice:

```py
import pygame
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("My title")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

background_color = (255, 255, 255)

i = 0
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(background_color)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(i, i, 40, 30))
    i += 1

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.flip()
    sleep(0.1)
```